# WiX Bundle bal:condition - util:RegistrySearch variable always false

Tags: installation, wix, registry, wix3.6

I want my install to fail if a third-party software element is not installed. I added a `Fragment` with a `util:RegistrySearch` and a `bal:Condition` to the `Bundle`, but I can't get it to work. `ThirdPartyCOMLibraryInstalled` never evaluates to true. I've confirmed that the key exists, and the value I use for `Key` is correct - I copy/pasted the name from the selected key in regedit. There aren't any errors in the log.

I'm building the installer with WiXTools 3.7 in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 64-bit and testing on both Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7 64-bit.

Searching online for other examples for `util:RegistrySearch` I ran across the following alternative forms for the condition test expression.

1. `ThirdPartyCOMLibraryInstalled = 0` - always False
2. `ThirdPartyCOMLibraryInstalled <> 1` - always True

Here is the `Bundle` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

    <Bundle Name="!(bind.packageName.MyApp)"
            Version="!(bind.packageVersion.MyApp)"
            Manufacturer="!(bind.packageManufacturer.MyApp)"
            UpgradeCode="a07ce1d5-a7ed-4d89-a7ee-fb13a5dd69ba"
            Copyright="Copyright (c) 2013 [Bundle/@Manufacturer]. All rights reserved."
            IconSourceFile="$(var.My_Application1.ProjectDir)MyCo.ico">

        <bal:Condition Message="ThirdParty Application COM Library Required. Please (re)install ThirdParty Application and ensure 'Windows API' and '.NET Components' are installed."
        >ThirdPartyCOMLibraryInstalled</bal:Condition>

        <Variable Name="InstallFolder"
                  Type="string"
                  Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]MyCo Systems\My_Application\"/>
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef
            Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense" >

            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
                ThemeFile="Resources\HyperlinkTheme.xml"
                LaunchTarget="[InstallFolder]My_Application.exe"
                LocalizationFile="Resources\HyperlinkTheme.wxl"
                SuppressRepair="yes"
                SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
                LicenseUrl=""
                LogoFile="Resources/MyCoLogoWt64.png"

            />
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist"/>
            <MsiPackage Id ="MyApp"
                        Vital="yes"
                        Name="My Application"
                        SourceFile="$(var.MyApp_Install.TargetDir)MyApp_Install.msi">
                <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION"
                             Value="[InstallFolder]" />
            </MsiPackage>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

    <Fragment>
      <util:RegistrySearch
            Variable="ThirdPartyCOMLibraryInstalled"
            Result="exists"
            Root="HKLM"
            Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\ThirdPartyId.Server\CLSID"/>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The root issue is that the `RegistrySearch` is in a separate `Fragment` that never gets referenced. Because nothing in the `Fragment` gets referenced the linker "optimizes away" the contents of the `Fragment` and the search is not included in your `Bundle`.

> Aside: you could argue that the fact that there is a reference to the variable mentioned in the search in the `Condition` that the linker should be able to figure out that the search is necessary. However, that doesn't work out in all cases.

Fortunately, the solution is quite simple! You even have to choose from one of two:

1. Move the `RegistrySearch` element to the `Bundle` element.
2. Add a `RegistrySearchRef` element in the `Bundle` element to reference the `RegistrySearch` in the `Fragment`. You will also need to give the `RegistrySearch` and `Id` attribute.

Personally, I like option two and I would probably even move the `Condition` into the `Fragment` as well to group all that stuff together. Something akin to:

```
<Bundle ...>
   <util:RegistrySearchRef Id='SearchForThirdParty' />

   ...

</Bundle>

<Fragment>
   <util:RegistrySearch
          Id='SearchForThirdParty' 
          Variable="ThirdPartyCOMLibraryInstalled" 
          Result="exists"
          Root="HKLM"
          Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\ThirdPartyId.Server\CLSID"/>

    <bal:Condition Message="ThirdParty Application COM Library Required. Please (re)install ThirdParty Application and ensure 'Windows API' and '.Net Components' are installed.">ThirdPartyCOMLibraryInstalled</bal:Condition>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

That should do it.

Comment: That works exactly.  Thank you.  I'd be happy to have this posted on the WiX documentation as one of the 'How To Guides' i.e. "Block bootstrapper installation based on a missing registry key"  What can I do to make that happen?

Comment: Sounds good. To add help, send a pull request against the wix38 branch with changes to files under: `src\chm\html` . Code is at http://wix.codeplex.com/