# Why does the WiX FileSearch and DetectCondition not work here?

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7

I want WiX to install [MSChart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ks53324%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for .NET 3.5 first, which is the ExePackage. At the moment, it always installs it even if it's already there. I detect if it's already installed by looking in the destination directory in the `MSChartInstalled FileSearch`

```
<Bundle ... etc.>
    <Chain>
        <ExePackage Id="mschart" SourceFile="MSChart.exe"
                    DetectCondition="MSChartInstalled"
                    Permanent="yes"
        />

        <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\Setup\bin\Release\Setup.msi" />
    </Chain>
</Bundle>

<Fragment>
    <util:FileSearch
          Id='SearchForMSChart'
          Variable="MSChartInstalled"
          Result="exists"
          Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]Microsoft Chart Controls\Assemblies\System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll"
       />
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to bring the Fragment into the bundle using a reference:

```
<bundle ... >
...
<util:FileSearchRef Id="SearchForMSChart"/>
...
```

As found in this [related question about checking the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108405/wix-bundle-balcondition-utilregistrysearch-variable-always-false).